# File obj loaded in three.js have wrong geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

In a script I load obj files from where i get only the geometry, after the definition of material in the main scena I add a mesh composed by the geometry an defined material, this for multiples obj files but with same material I obtain two distinct render results as is visible in the following screenshots:
[image: The wrong render]

[image: The right render]

The right render for my purpose is the second, twice obj are exported with the same options from Rhinoceros, but only one of the two have some "empty faces", how i can fix it?

---

### Edit 1

```
objLoader.load('obj-url', function(object) {
            var temp = new THREE.Geometry();
            object.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    temp.fromBufferGeometry(child.geometry);
                }
            });

            setPlanarUVA(temp);
            temp = new THREE.Mesh(temp, material);
            temp.needsUpdate = true;
            scene.add(temp);

            self.g.needsUpdate = true;

            function setPlanarUVA(geometry, side) {
                var self = this,
                    gData = this.g.gData;
                geometry.computeBoundingBox();
                var max = geometry.boundingBox.max,
                    min = geometry.boundingBox.min,
                    faces = geometry.faces,
                    offset = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.z, 0 - min.y),
                    range = new THREE.Vector2(max.z - min.z, max.y - min.y);

                geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {

                    //salvo i vertici della faccia che sto processando
                    var v1 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].a],
                        v2 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].b],
                        v3 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].c];

                    var v1_y = (((v1.y + offset.x) / range.y)),
                        v2_y = (((v2.y + offset.x) / range.y)),
                        v3_y = (((v3.y + offset.x) / range.y));

                    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
                        new THREE.Vector2((v1.z + offset.x) / range.x, v1_y),
                        new THREE.Vector2((v2.z + offset.x) / range.x, v2_y),
                        new THREE.Vector2((v3.z + offset.x) / range.x, v3_y)
                    ]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Would be nice to provide your actual code if possible.

Comment: a quick fix is to turn on `DoubleSide` in your material. The correct way is to fix the model with all triangles having their face definitions in a counter-clockwise order.